# /tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:227:7: error: conflicting types for 'CreateListNode' | /tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:171:19: error: redefinition of 'new'

Tags: c

I have written a code in C language and I have a few errors which I have no idea why it is giving me errors.
Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong? And how I could fix it?
When I compile the code, I get errors with statements that I do not understand...
I created a program for creating nodes and deleting them.
Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//declare struct
typedef struct node {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char PUID[10];
    int age;
    struct node* next;
}NODE;

int commands();
void menu();
void CreateListNoNodes();
NODE* InsertFront(NODE* head, NODE* new);
NODE* InsertFront(NODE* head, NODE* new);
void InsertMiddle(NODE** head, NODE* new, int index);
void InsertEnd(NODE** head, NODE* new);
void DeleteFront(NODE** head);
void DeleteMiddle(NODE** head, int index);
void DeleteEnd(NODE** head);
void Traverse(NODE* head);
void LookUpByIndex(NODE* head, int index);
//Declare functions



int main()
{
    commands();

    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    //function to list menu
    printf("1. Create a List with no nodes and just a start pointer\n");
    printf("2. Create a list with a single node\n");
    printf("3. Insert a node at the front of the list\n");
    printf("4. insert a node in the middle of the of the list\n");
    printf("5. insert a node at the end of the of the list\n");
    printf("6. delete the first node in the list\n");
    printf("7. delete a node in the middle of the list\n");
    printf("8. delete a node at the end of the list\n");
    printf
    ("9.  traverse the list based on some key value in the data portion of the node\n");
    printf
    ("10. find a particular node by an index number. Return -1 if that index does not exist\n");
    printf("11. Exit the program\n\n");
    printf("Please enter a number: ");

}

int commands()
{
    int input;

    NODE* head = NULL;

    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];

    char PUID[10];
    int age = 0;
    
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    //infinite loop to keep asking for menu
    while (1) {
        menu();
        scanf("%d", &input);
       
        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
            if (head == NULL)
            {

                CreateListNoNodes(i);
                int i = 1;

            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nError! A list is already created. \n");
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("Please Enter First Name: ");
                scanf("%s", firstName);
                printf("Please Enter Last name: ");
                scanf("%s", lastName);
                printf("Please Enter PUID: ");
                scanf("%s", PUID);
                printf("Please Enter Age: ");
                scanf("%d", &age);
                printf("\n");
                head = CreateListNode(head, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
                printf("Node has been created:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", head->firstName, head->lastName, head->PUID, head->age);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nError! A list is already created. ");
            }

            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Please Enter First Name: ");
            scanf("%s", firstName);
            printf("Please Enter Last name: ");
            scanf("%s", lastName);
            printf("Please Enter PUID: ");
            scanf("%s", PUID);
            printf("Please Enter Age: ");
            scanf("%d", &age);
            printf("\n");
            NODE* new = NULL;
            new = CreateListNode(new, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
            new = InsertFront(head, new);
            head = new;
            printf("Node has been created:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", head->firstName, head->lastName, head->PUID, head->age);

            break;

        case 4:
            printf("Please Enter First Name: ");
            scanf("%s", firstName);
            printf("Please Enter Last name: ");
            scanf("%s", lastName);
            printf("Please Enter PUID: ");
            scanf("%s", PUID);
            printf("Please Enter Age: ");
            scanf("%d", &age);
            printf("Please Enter Index: ");
            scanf("%d", &index);
            printf("\n");
            NODE* new = NULL;
            new = CreateListNode(new, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
            InsertMiddle(&head, new, index);
            break;

        case 5:
            printf("Please Enter First Name: ");
            scanf("%s", firstName);
            printf("Please Enter Last name: ");
            scanf("%s", lastName);
            printf("Please Enter PUID: ");
            scanf("%s", PUID);
            printf("Please Enter Age: ");
            scanf("%d", &age);
            NODE* new = NULL;
            new = CreateListNode(new, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
            InsertEnd(&head, new);

            break;

        case 6:
            DeleteFront(&head);
            break;

        case 7:
            printf("Please Enter index: ");
            scanf("%d", &index);
            printf("\n");
            DeleteMiddle(&head, index);

            break;

        case 8:
            DeleteEnd(&head);

            break;

        case 9:
            Traverse(head);
            break;

        case 10:
            printf("Please Enter index: ");
            scanf("%d", &index);
            printf("\n");
            LookUpByIndex(head, index);
            break;

        case 11:
            printf("Exiting...");
            return 0;
            break;


        default:
            printf("Error! Please Enter Number From 1 to 11.\n\n");
            menu();
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

//Create list with no nodes
void CreateListNoNodes() {
    printf("List With No Nodes Created.\n");
 
}

//Create list with a node
NODE* CreateListNode(NODE* new, char* firstName, char* lastName, char* PUID, int age){
    new = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(new->firstName, firstName);
    strcpy(new->lastName, lastName);
    strcpy(new->PUID, PUID);
    new->age = age;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

//Insert node in front
NODE* InsertFront(NODE* head, NODE* new) {
    new->next = head;
    return new;
}

//Insert node in middle
void InsertMiddle(NODE** head, NODE* new, int index) {
    NODE* temp = *head;
    if (index == 0)
    {
        InsertFront(temp, new);
        *head = new;
        printf("Node has been created:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", new->firstName, new->lastName, new->PUID, new->age);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! Please Try Another Index.");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        new->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = new;
        printf("Node has been created:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", new->firstName, new->lastName, new->PUID, new->age);
    }
    return;
}

//Insert node in end
void InsertEnd(NODE** head, NODE* new) {
    NODE* temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new;
    printf("Node has been created:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", new->firstName, new->lastName, new->PUID, new->age);
    return;
}

//Delete node in front
void DeleteFront(NODE** head) {
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList is empty");
        return;
    }
    NODE* temp = (*head)->next;
    printf("\nThe following node has been deleted:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n ", (*head)->firstName, (*head)->lastName, (*head)->PUID, (*head)->age);
    *head = temp;

    return;
}

//Delete node in middle
void DeleteMiddle(NODE** head, int index) {
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList Empty");
        return;
    }
    NODE* delNode = *head;
    NODE* keepNode = *head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        keepNode = delNode;
        delNode = delNode->next;
        if (delNode == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! Please Try Another Index.");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (delNode != NULL)
    {
        if (delNode == *head)
        {
            *head = (*head)->next;
        }
        keepNode->next = delNode->next;
        delNode->next = NULL;
        printf("\nThe following node has been deleted:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n ", delNode->firstName, delNode->lastName, delNode->PUID, delNode->age);

    }
    return;
}

////Delete node in end
void DeleteEnd(NODE** head) {
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nList Empty!");
        return;
    }
    NODE* delNode = *head;
    NODE* secondNode = *head;
    while (delNode->next != NULL)
    {
        secondNode = delNode;
        delNode = delNode->next;
    }
    if (delNode == *head)
    {
        *head = NULL;
        printf("\nThe following node has been deleted:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n ", delNode->firstName, delNode->lastName, delNode->PUID, delNode->age);
    }
    else
    {
        secondNode->next = NULL;
        printf("\nThe following node has been deleted:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n ", delNode->firstName, delNode->lastName, delNode->PUID, delNode->age);
    }

    return;
}

//Traverse
void Traverse(NODE* head) {
    NODE* temp = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List Empty!");
    }
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", temp->PUID);
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf(" -> ");
        }
    }
    return;
}

//Look up node by index
void LookUpByIndex(NODE* head, int index) {
    NODE* current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (count == index)
        {
            printf("Node At index:\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nPUID: %s\nAge: %d\n", current->firstName, current->lastName, current->PUID, current->age);
            return;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Error! Please Try Another Index.");
    return;
}
```

Below are the errors and warning:

```
gcc /tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c -lm
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c: In function 'commands':
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:117:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CreateListNode'; did you mean 'CreateListNoNodes'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  117 |                 head = CreateListNode(head, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        CreateListNoNodes
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:117:22: warning: assignment to 'NODE *' {aka 'struct node *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  117 |                 head = CreateListNode(head, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
      |                      ^
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:138:17: warning: assignment to 'NODE *' {aka 'struct node *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  138 |             new = CreateListNode(new, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
      |                 ^
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:157:19: error: redefinition of 'new'
  157 |             NODE* new = NULL;
      |                   ^~~
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:137:19: note: previous definition of 'new' was here
  137 |             NODE* new = NULL;
      |                   ^~~
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:158:17: warning: assignment to 'NODE *' {aka 'struct node *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  158 |             new = CreateListNode(new, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
      |                 ^
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:171:19: error: redefinition of 'new'
  171 |             NODE* new = NULL;
      |                   ^~~
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:157:19: note: previous definition of 'new' was here
  157 |             NODE* new = NULL;
      |                   ^~~
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:172:17: warning: assignment to 'NODE *' {aka 'struct node *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  172 |             new = CreateListNode(new, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
      |                 ^
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c: At top level:
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:227:7: error: conflicting types for 'CreateListNode'
  227 | NODE* CreateListNode(NODE* new, char* firstName, char* lastName, char* PUID, int age){
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pdG7WaW1iq.c:117:24: note: previous implicit declaration of 'CreateListNode' was here
  117 |                 head = CreateListNode(head, firstName, lastName, PUID, age);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I need an explanation of what each error and meanings mean... I am really new to programming so I am really struggling to learn this by myself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve], with emphasis on the **minimal** part. Also please copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question, and add comments in the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: There are a lot more errors in your code than this.  When dealing with errors from the compiler, always address them one at a time from the top down and don't ignore warnings.  Also, an error or warning sometimes comes with a note immediately following it giving you more information on what the problem might be, so pay attention to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you missed to mention function proto type before the function call. Please use below function proto type before actual function call. we need to tell the compiler about this function's name, arguments and its return type before actual function call happen.

```
NODE* CreateListNode(NODE* new, char* firstName, char* lastName, char* PUID, int age);
//Declare functions
```

And you can use different variable names in line no 147 and 161 like new1, new2. Multible declaration in a single block is not allowed. we can not use same varible name, instead we can use different variable names.

```
NODE* new1 = NULL;
NODE* new2 = NULL;
```

Then you program may be successfully compiled.